# Tracking utm parameters with universal analytics

Tags: php, universal-analytics, utm

Previously I was using ga.js (asynchronous - _gaq.push) at time I was 99% able to capture all utm parameters.
Later on I have update the code and moved to analytics.js (universal - ga send), from then I am unable to capture a single utm parameter.

Do I need to change the code to to capture utm parameters as now I am using analytics.js ?

My code :

```
session_start();
$utm_parameters=substr($_REQUEST['__utmz'],strpos($_REQUEST['__utmz'],"utmcsr="));
$utm_source=substr($_REQUEST['__utmz'],strpos($_REQUEST['__utmz'],"utmcsr="));
$utm_source=substr($utm_source,0,strpos($utm_source,"|"));
$utm_source=substr($utm_source,7);
$utm_media=substr($_REQUEST['__utmz'],strpos($_REQUEST['__utmz'],"utmcmd="));
$utm_media=substr($utm_media,0,strpos($utm_media,"|"));
$utm_media=substr($utm_media,7);

if ($_SESSION['url'] != null) {
    $utm_parameters = $_SESSION['url'];
}

if ($_SESSION['utm_source'] != null) {
    $utm_source = $_SESSION['utm_source'];
}

if ($_SESSION['utm_medium'] != null) {
    $utm_media = $_SESSION['utm_medium'];
    // echo 'utm_media='.$_SESSION['utm_medium'];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Universal Analytics does not employ the same cookies as Google Analytics. the UTMZ cookie does not exist anymore, and the traffic source you were retrieving before isn't kept in the cookie.

To overcome this you will need to create your own cookie. Try this project: https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative

You can also run the old code ga.js side by side with Universal Analytics, but this is not a permanent solution since the support for ga.js will be discontinued at one point.

Answer (score 2):

These cookies are no more in use.

For utm parameter tracking, you need to tag them manually in your url and need to capture programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was download ga.js from google, stripped away all the AJAX stuff, and run it from our own domain now. That way we have the __utmz cookie, without having the problem of doubly tracking (once via ga.js, once via analytics.js).
Certainly not the most elegant solution out there, but it works, and works exactly the way we were use to.

Comment: Can you put this on github? Thanks.

Comment: I've put it in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/rpkamp/9e82cf4ff483c06644e1 -- like it says in the title, use at your own risk. I'm not responsible for anything that happens when you use this code. It works fine for us, but YMMV :)